# Assembly language in Jasmin - getting syntax error

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, jasmin

In putty I am attempting to create a Jasmin program that, when assembled and ran as a Java program, will output the integer "431". When I attempt to assemble the program the console says there is a syntax error on line 11. I am having trouble figuring out what it is. Here is my code:

```
.class public Lab3_JasminExample
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
        aload_0
        invokespecial java/lang/Object/<init>()V
        return
.end method

.method public static main ([Ljava.lang.String;)V
        .limit stack 10
        .limit locals 10

        getstatic  java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;

        sipush 431

        invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
        return
.end method
```

Line 11 would be ".limit stack 10" and I can't see what is wrong with how I wrote that. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors may be reported on a line but be triggered by previous (or following!) lines, so always look around the offending line.

My Jasmin (version 2.4) correctly reports the error on line 10

```
a.j:10: Warning - Syntax error.
.method public static main ([Ljava.lang.String;)V
                                                  ^
```

This is a silly mistake really: there is space between the method name (`main`) and its descriptor (`([Ljava.lang.String;)V`)

Line 10 should be `.method public static main([Ljava.lang.String;)V`